# How to integrate Microsoft login in Android?

Tags: android

I downloaded one sample code from the following link:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android

After this, I updated CLIENT_ID and REDIRECT_URI in Constants.
I'm getting following error

[image: error page screen shot]

If any SDK available for Microsoft login, please provide me the links.

Thank you.

Comment: library you are using has this disclaimer - Important: This preview SDK has been deprecated and is no longer being maintained. We recommend that you use Microsoft Graph and the associated Microsoft Graph SDKs instead.

Answer (score 1):

I got following link to integrate Microsoft Graph in Android app :
[Get started with Microsoft Graph in Android App](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/android)

You can download sample code from given following url at 3rd point "Start Coding": [Sample code link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start?appID=7b918cd6-43e7-4865-808d-e59f72217551&appName=My%20Android%20App&redirectUrl=http://localhost:8000&platform=option-android)